# matplotlib subplot and open different netcdf files

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I would like to plot a figure with 25 (or less) subplots, over 5 rows and 5 cols.
I use basemap and need to open 25 different netcdf files

I have :

```
nc0= cdms.open('fic1.nc')

nc1=cdms.open('fic2.nc') ....

m= Basemap(....)

fig = plt.figure()

for i in range(24): 

    fig.subplot(5,5,i+1)

    X,Y=m(lon,lat)

    Data=nc?('rod')

    plot=m.pcolor(X,Y,Data[0,:,:])


plt.show()
```

How can I do to open the netcdf file (nc?) when I loop over the plots ?

Thanks

Comment: Please format your code!

Answer (score 0):

```
# make all of your sub-plots at once
fig, ax_list = plt.subplots(5, 5)
# loop over each axes + your file names
for ax, fname in zip(np.ravel(ax_list), list_of_filenames):
    # write code that deals with one file and one axes
    nc = cdms.open(fname)
    m = Basemap()
    m.pcolor()
```

Comment: Thanks but I do not understand where I precise that my files are fic1.nc, fic2.nc, etc

Comment: @user2050187 You just specify the `list_of_filenames` variable at the top of your script, or you use e.g. `sys.argv[1:]` to grab them from the command line. Depending on the format of the filenames, you could also use something like `glob.glob("fic*.nc").

Comment: list_of_filename=('fic1.nc','fic2.nc',..., 'fic25.nc')  doesn't work ...I just get one plot and the other spaces are empty

Comment: That is technically a tuple, but yes, that should work.